# Deriving an expression from Navier-Stokes under creeping flow

Tags: physical-chemistry

So I'm trying to derive
$$\mu\nabla^2\vec{v}=\nabla P-\rho g$$
from Navier-Stokes equation
$$\begin{align}\rho \left(\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot(\nabla\vec{v})\right)&=\rho\vec{g}-\nabla P+\mu\nabla^2\vec{v}\\
\rho \left(\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot(\nabla\vec{v})\right)-\mu\nabla^2\vec{v}&=\rho\vec{g}-\nabla P
\end{align}$$

under creeping flow.

I began with looking at the left-hand side of Navier-Stokes equation, which I expanded to:

$$\rho \left(\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+v_x\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y}+v_z\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z}\right)-\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

Because of the creeping flow I new that $v_x\approx v_y\approx v_z\approx0$. Because of this I can therefore write the left-hand side as:

$$\rho \frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}-\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

But from here I am stuck. I asked a friend who said that since $v_x\approx v_y\approx v_z\approx0$ we can also remove the $\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}$-term but I find this mathematically incorrect since the derivate of a function isn't necessarily small just because the function is small. As an example the function
$$\vec{v}(t)=((t+1000)^2-10^6)\vec{e_x}+((t+100)^3-10^6)\vec{e_y}+((t+50)^2-2500)\vec{e_z}$$ is small when $t=0$ but that isn't true for the derivate in $t=0$.
Is it something I'm missing when it comes to creeping flow? Is it that $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ are constantly small and therefore we can se them as constant functions and therefore the derivate is also neglectable?

Comment: Wow. Rheology etc. are usually fine subjects for chem.SE, but this one might be better in physics or engineering.  Anyway under creep flow, all velocities should be constant in time. Re is small, and everything should be in steady state.